# How do I specify module directories for Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I can't specify modulesDirectories for Jest like as in Webpack. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jestpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jestpack) might work for you as it runs built tests so all Webpack features are supported.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question. Support has now been added to jest so now you can simply add `moduleDirectories` to your jest config. If you're using package.json that would be

```
"jest": {
    "moduleDirectories": [
        "node_modules", 
        "yourdirectoryhere"
     ],
 ...
}
```